# Auto populate Subscription term in Quote line editor

Tags: quote, cpq

I've tried to set a subscription length to 12 months on the product object, but it doesn't auto populate when you select the product on the quote line editor.

is there a way to auto-populate subscription term on the quote line editor ?

Answer (score 3):

The Subscription Term on the Product and Quote are controlling different things.

On the product, this is saying that a subscription product is priced at X cost for that term. If you have a product with a subscription term of 12 months and quote it on a Quote for 3 years, CPQ needs to take the 12 month price x 3.

It is possible that you could select a product with a 12 month subscription term and then select another product with a 6 month subscription term - you would need logic to decide how you want to handle that.

You could auto-populate the subscription field on Quote with a WF Rule on creation or change the default value of the field, but that isn't dependent on your product. You could also use a Price Rule to set that field - that would run when the quote is saved or the user hits the calculate button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What object would i base the workflow rule on, if I was to chose the quote object wouldn't it populate the subscription term field after the quote is saved ?

Comment: You could base it off the Quote Object. Since you need to have saved the Quote before going into the Quote Line Editor, it would always be populated there.

Comment: But the quote object wouldn't have the products in the quote line editor before adding the products in the quote line editor, and once the products are added there is no logic handling that auto subscription term population.

Comment: Right, if you need to have it come from the products, you'll be stuck using price rules. But you also need to consider the fact that you could have multiple products with different terms and account for that

Comment: Well we have a "standard subscription term" in the product object in Salesforce and I was wondering if I could use that if a product is a subscription.